# Can we solve covering segments by points problem by sorting left start point

Tags: c++, python-3.x, algorithm

I have seen a lot of articles and solutions about this problem always sorted by the right endpoint
I try to solve it by sorting the left start point and I don't understand why it doesn't work in some cases,this is my code:

```
struct Segment {
  int start, end;
};
bool comp (struct Segment s1 , struct Segment s2)
{
    int a = s1.start;
    int b = s2.start;
    return a < b ;
}
vector<int> optimal_points(vector<Segment> &segments) {
  vector<int> points;
  std::sort(segments.begin(),segments.end(),comp);

  int i = 0 ;
  int n = segments.size();
  while (i < n )
  {
      int o = i ;
      i++;
      while (i < n && segments[i].start <= segments[o].end)
      {

          i++;

      }

     points.push_back(segments[i-1].start);
  }

  return points;
}
```

If anyone don't know this problem(covering segments by points) this is explanation about it

https://medium.com/competitive/covering-segments-by-points-fc2c56c4b038

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it, like for example describing the problem you have with the code you show and what debugging attempts you made. And to remove unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some segment might start and end **before** `segments[o]` end, and you just miss it.

Segment array {(1:10), (2:3), (4:5), (6:7)} is sorted by the left end.

For i=0 you assign o=0 and compare 2,4,6 with 10 until i reaches 4.

Now you push 6 into points. But what about covering (2:3) and (4:5)?

Comment: I sorted segments by the start points , that means always segments[i].start > segments[o].start(because always i at least would be o+1 in while loop) so means any segments[i].start <= segments[o].end will be overlapping 
according to this condition :
seg1.start <=seg2.start <=seg2,end<=seg1.end 
and visa versa
what I missed it exactly?    @MBo

Comment: Look at addition.